# Error when launching the graph (DSEGraphFrame )

Tags: scala, apache-spark, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph, dse-graph-frames

I have a dse graph in validation/prod environement.
The problem occurs when I try to launch a DSEGraphFrame query using Spark in Scala.

```
val graph = spark.dseGraph("my_graph")
```

generates the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: The method
>   DseGraphRpc.getSchemaBlob does not exist. Make sure that the required
>   component for that method is active/enabled
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:40)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:26)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:284)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:49)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:37)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.execute(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.SessionProxy.invoke(SessionProxy.scala:37)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.execute(Unknown Source)
>       at com.datastax.bdp.util.rpc.RpcUtil.callInternal(RpcUtil.java:57)
>       at com.datastax.bdp.util.rpc.RpcUtil.call(RpcUtil.java:40)
>       at com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.DseGraphRpc.callGetSchema(DseGraphRpc.java:45)
>       at com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.graphframe.DseGraphFrame$$anonfun$getSchemaFromServer$1.apply(DseGraphFrame.scala:586)
>       at com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.graphframe.DseGraphFrame$$anonfun$getSchemaFromServer$1.apply(DseGraphFrame.scala:586)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:115)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:114)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:158)
>       at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:114)
>       at com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.graphframe.DseGraphFrame$.getSchemaFromServer(DseGraphFrame.scala:586)
>       at com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.graphframe.DseGraphFrameBuilder$.apply(DseGraphFrameBuilder.scala:257)
>       at com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.graphframe.SparkSessionFunctions.dseGraph(SparkSessionFunctions.scala:20)

What could I do to run DSEGraphFrame properly?

Comment: What version of DSE? Are you running it on DSE Analytics, or on the external Spark?

Comment: Did you start DSE with Graph and Analytics enabled?

Comment: thanks Alex and Artem  for your help , the problem is the graph activation in a node

Comment: I have a question plz : why i should activate Graph(enabled)  in all my nodes ? there is a way to start it even if in a node isn't activate ?                                         dse : 6.0.4 + External spark +byos 6.7.0.jar

Comment: TLDR. All DSE nodes are equals in Datacenter and client can connect to any of them or even connect to all of then. So the DGF client selected the node without Graph in your case and fail to receive Graph metadata.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from a node in dse cluster  wich the graph isn't activated